# How to create a stock management system for a company?

Tags: management

I am new to WordPress. I want to create a stock management system for a company. The website will be visible for the employees. The problem is that I don't need to sell something, or to have prices or costumers or to transport products. The employee can export the products out of the stock or can add them back(import them). When I do it with WooCommerce, there is a cart and checkout payments, I don't need these functions.

Comment: You can custom write an application or use CSS to hide the un-needed aspects of WooCommerce.